# Strategies for Encryption with Django + Postgres?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, encryption

I'm going to be storing a few sensitive pieces of information (SSN, Bank Accounts, etc) so they'll obviously need to be encrypted.  What strategies do you recommend?

Should I do all the encryption/decryption in the web app itself?  Should I use something like pgcrypto and have the conversions done on the DB side?  Something else entirely?

Also, if you think I should do encryption on the web app side, what Python libraries would you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you protecting against? If attacker would get access to your DB/filesystem, he would find how you decrypt data & keys. Hiding your encription key is not an easy task (and rarely implemented in "usual" applications).

I would spend more time on protecting the server and fixing all general security issues.

Comment: I agree, and I'm planning to use a fully managed service to run my production setup for precisely that reason -- I know just enough about linux system administration to know how little I know :)

That being said, I'd still like to encrypt the fields.  I view it as the same type of activity as locking the doors to your house.  It's still pretty easy to break in, but it adds a bit of a deterrent.

Comment: Then you should stick all your encription & keys on webapp side, so that if DB stolen attacker gets nothing. If files stolen - also nothing. So hardcode key in code, and encrypt/decript all data using AES from standard Python library.

Comment: I guess you can also put your key in some wird location, so when blindly copying root of your site, attacker would not get the key.

Comment: When you say "AES from standard Python library", what library are you referring to?  Does Python ship with a library for AES encryption?  Most of the recommendations I've seen are for pycrypto (3rd party).

Comment: http://www.amk.ca/python/code/crypto.html
Ops, actually not in a standard libs, but recommended.

Answer (score 5):

You can also check **django-pgcrypto**: https://github.com/dcwatson/django-pgcrypto

Answer (score 5):

I agree that first you need to consider your overall security model and what threat avenues might be the most risk, a la this article:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16939/is-it-generally-a-bad-idea-to-encrypt-database-fields

but also take a look at these for encrypted fields in Django:

encrypted fields:  https://github.com/svetlyak40wt/django-fields

more encrypted fields:

https://github.com/defrex/django-encrypted-fields,
https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions

Comment: django-extensions seems to have removed encrypted fields. https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/commit/c557bb7b08a005df98e6c5a8309afe77442e1fd3

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to do the encryption in your web app side and you are using Django for your app, you can take a look django-extensions, especially EncryptedCharField and EncryptedTextField. -> https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/master/docs/field_extensions.rst

Comment: django-extensions seems to have removed encrypted fields. https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/commit/c557bb7b08a005df98e6c5a8309afe77442e1fd3